# transpose wide to long with new var in SAS

Tags: database, sas

I have a dataset that is a list of individuals and if they were involved in a program over a number of years.

| ID | kl2_2016 | kl2_2017 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ajones | 1 | 0 |
| bsmith | 0 | 1 |

...and so forth

I want it to look like this

| Obs | year | total_service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016 | 20 |
| 2 | 2017 | 71 |

I am using this code

```
proc sql;
    create table year_service as
    select
    distinct 
            sum(kl2_2016) as kl2_2016,
            sum(kl2_2017) as kl2_2017,
            sum(kl2_2018) as kl2_2018,
            sum(kl2_2019) as kl2_2019,
            sum(kl2_2020) as kl2_2020,
            sum(kl2_2021) as kl2_2021,
            sum(kl2_2022) as kl2_2022,
            sum(kl2_2023) as kl2_2023,
            sum(kl2_2024) as kl2_2024,
            sum(kl2_2025) as kl2_2025
            from have
;
quit;

proc transpose data=year_service 
   out=year_service_long;
   var kl2_2016-kl2_2025;
   
run;
```

but it's not what I want. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I suspect you need to expand the example data, for example what happens when a person is in more than one year. Can you also include the results that will match the input, even if it's very basic.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to have `PROC TRANSPOSE` handle the columns for you, this will handle changes in the input data much more gracefully. I'd approach it like so:

```
/* Example input. */
data have;
   ID = "ajones"; kl2_2016 = 1; kl2_2017 = 0; output;
   ID = "bsmith"; kl2_2016 = 0; kl2_2017 = 1; output;
run;

proc sort data=have; by id; run;

/* Put the different years (values of KL2_:) on separate records. */
proc transpose data=have out=long;
   by id;
   var kl2_:;
run;

/* Summarize in whatever way you want. */
proc sql;
   create table want as
      select distinct input(scan(_name_, 2, "_"), best.) as year,
                      sum(col1) as total_service from long group by 1;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Proc TABULATE` can present the results in such a way.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20231020);
  do personid = 1 to 1000;
    array x kl2_2016-kl2_2025;
    do over x;
      x = ( rand('uniform') < 0.45 );
    end;
    output;
  end;
  format kl2_: 2.;
run;

ods html file='counts.html';
proc tabulate data=have;
  var kl:;
  table kl2:, sum;
run;
ods html close;
```

[image]